# Can some questions have a "bounty", as they do at MathOverflow ?

Tags: discussion, se2.0

Even though this is not a location for original research, can questions still have a bounty?  The following question was just posted: [How do you determine if a point sits inside a polygon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-do-you-determine-if-a-point-sits-inside-a-polygon) and it looks to me as though this is a solved problem (maybe requiring the assumption of convexity, or maybe it is solved in general) - but it also looks like it would require a response more involved than the other questions that have come up so far...  should this question, or any questions here, have a bounty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [**the faq**](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq)

> Questions must be at least **2** days old to be eligible for a bounty.

You should be able to set bounties, but only after questions are two days old.

Most (all) questions at this point are less than two days old, so you should not really be seeing any bounty-able questions at this point.

Comment: As far as I know, it is.  I've been able to offer bounties on WebApps.  But I'm going to trust the FAQ =)